# Al pulsar botón no me ejecuta alert en javascript externo usando jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un archivo html login de un modelo bootstrap al cual le quiero referenciar un archivo js para que bote un alert al presionar un botón.

El punto es que por más que lo intente no me muestra nada y eso que he probado que la ruta sea correcta con ctrl, verificado el id del botón o creado un html simple el cual sí me corre al referenciar el mismo js.

Éste es el html bootstrap y javascript:

```html
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Login</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha256-916EbMg70RQy9LHiGkXzG8hSg9EdNy97GazNG/aiY1w=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/metisMenu/2.7.0/metisMenu.min.css" integrity="sha256-OufFdETrXbY5YtILsSTzlY+4Ttmq+hUfR1mMYLmKlWo=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/3.3.7+1/css/sb-admin-2.min.css" integrity="sha256-WeMGw+d+qR+l2h9TzmC+jTME4zy5zYzG8E6FbPikzeM=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha256-eZrrJcwDc/3uDhsdt61sL2oOBY362qM3lon1gyExkL0=" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <!--Js externo-->
    <script src="../../js/jsadmin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- lo pongo en línea (autor de la edición) para reproducir correctamente el error -->
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#BtnLogin').click(function() {
          alert('hola mundo!');
        });
      });
    </script>


</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Please Sign In</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form role="form">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" type="email" autofocus>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me">Remember Me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Change this to a button or input when using this as a form -->
                                <button type="button" id="BtnLogin" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Login</button>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-U5ZEeKfGNOja007MMD3YBI0A3OSZOQbeG6z2f2Y0hu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/metisMenu/2.7.0/metisMenu.min.js" integrity="sha256-EdeVuolWxmuLTapvaUaXTYIYKTIlhc0nUEGPEMn8MhQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/3.3.7+1/js/sb-admin-2.min.js" integrity="sha256-Y0Z5pT4qPGaoUSHoxW+J8fIWjQnjc7v03WBEUnt9SQ0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: El código parece correcto. Cómo se llama el archivo js? Es `jsadmin.js`? Si es así, te has asegurado que la ruta sea correcta (dos directorios arriba y dentro de la carpeta js)?

Comment: Si tu script es `jsadmin.js`, el problema es que no tienes jQuery listo aún y el dólar no está definido, si pones tu script al final de la página te funcionará.

Comment: Es cuestión de estructura del html y javascript te recomiendo usar el tu proyecto mvc te invito a visitar mi canal hablo un poco de este tipo de situaciones https://youtu.be/Xq10Ki20IvM aquí hablo un poco acerca.!! espero y te sirva saludos compartan para seguirme animando a crear tutorales

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El orden de carga de tus archivos javascript puede que no sea el correcto. En la consola de Javascript de tu navegador debería estar lanzando uno de los siguientes mensajes de error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ready' of undefined
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Es debido a que intentas hacer uso de las funciones de jQuery antes de que éstas se hayan cargado (las has puesto el final de tu archivo HTML).

Para solucionarlo tienes dos soluciones que te expongo a continuación:

### Cargar tu script tras jQuery:

Poner un orden correcto en la carga de recursos para tener en cuenta sus dependencias:

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="../../js/jsadmin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

### Uso de `defer`

Agregar el atributo [`defer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) a la etiqueta `<script>` de tu código javascript se ejecute en último lugar, tras la carga del resto de recursos de la página:

```
<script src="../../js/jsadmin.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
```

Ten en cuenta que el uso de `defer` en varios recursos hace que éstos se carguen y ejecuten en el mismo orden en el que están definidos en el documento, por lo que yo, personalmente, **te recomiendo la primera solución**.

Comment: Funciono!! Chicos me han ayudado genial, Oscar , Dios te bendiga y gracias por la leccion lo tomare muy en cuenta!! (Poner el script al final de body es la solucion!!!)

Comment: Si te funcionó te agradecería que marcaras la respuesta como correcta. Gracias.