# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined Jquery

Tags: html, jquery

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

estuve buscando una solución y no encuentro nada que me sirva para arreglarlo
estoy, tratando de crear un nav que baje un menu y muestre iconos de los proyectos que estoy creando 
este es mi codigo html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_static/css/style.css">
    <script src="_static/js/main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav class="nav-bar-global" id="nav-bar-global">
        <ul class="menu-top">
          <li id="menu-global-xs"><a><i class="fas fa-bars"></i> Proyectos</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="close-global" id="games">
            <li><a href="#"><img class="game-icon" src="" alt=""></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img class="game-icon" src="" alt=""></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img class="game-icon" src="" alt=""></a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

y lo relacionado al menu en el main.js

```
$(function(){
  $("#menu-global-xs").click(function () {
    if ($('#games').hasClass('close-global')) {
      $('#games').removeClass('close-global')
      $('#games').addClass('show-global')
    }else {
      $('#games').removeClass('show-global')
      $('#games').addClass('close-global')
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hola, puedes revisar [Jquery: ReferenceError: $ is not defined](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/175832/jquery-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Comment: Cambia el orden en que cargas tus `scripts`, debes colocar primero `Jquery` y luego tu propio script `main.js`. Saludos

Comment: Problema de orden de carga de scripts, duplicado de [al pulsar botón no me ejecuta alert en javascript externo usando jQuery](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/111497/al-pulsar-bot%c3%b3n-no-me-ejecuta-alert-en-javascript-externo-usando-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jquery tiene que estar antes de todos los scripts

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_static/css/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="_static/js/main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  </head>
```

Answer (score 2):

Al momento de importar los `scripts` `jquery` tiene que ir antes que otros `scripts` como ya te lo mencionaron

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_static/css/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="_static/js/main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
```

Además de esto, tienes que ejecutar la función que estas haciendo después de que haya cargado la pagina todos los elementos, ya sea con un `$(document).ready()` o ejecutando la función abajo.

`ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#menu-global-xs").click(function () {
    if ($('#games').hasClass('close-global')) {
      $('#games').removeClass('close-global')
      $('#games').addClass('show-global')
    }else {
      $('#games').removeClass('show-global')
      $('#games').addClass('close-global')
    }
  });
});
```

ó abajo

`Jquery`

```
function ejecutarJquery(){
  $("#menu-global-xs").click(function () {
    if ($('#games').hasClass('close-global')) {
      $('#games').removeClass('close-global')
      $('#games').addClass('show-global')
    }else {
      $('#games').removeClass('show-global')
      $('#games').addClass('close-global')
    }
  });
});
```

`HTML`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_static/css/style.css">
    <script src="_static/js/main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav class="nav-bar-global" id="nav-bar-global">
        <ul class="menu-top">
          <li id="menu-global-xs"><a><i class="fas fa-bars"></i> Proyectos</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="close-global" id="games">
            <li><a href="#"><img class="game-icon" src="" alt=""></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img class="game-icon" src="" alt=""></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img class="game-icon" src="" alt=""></a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  <script> 
    ejecutarJquery();
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Espero y te sirva, saludos.